# редактирование комментария в textarea включая переносы строк

Tags: php, javascript, html

Пользователь оставляет комментарий и в течении трех минут может его редактировать.
При редактирование текст комментария попадает в `textarea`. В базе он хранится как тип `text`. При выводе в `textarea` переносы пропадают. Каким образом это исправить?

Comment: LF не должны пропадать при выводе в textarea. Они пропадут только если **вы** каким-то образом меняли текст. Смотрите свой код сохранения/вывода и убирайте лишнее.

Answer (score 2):

На выбор:

а) За счет стилей: как известно, тег <pre> заставляет переводы строк работать. Вы можете имитировать это поведение у любого элемента указав правило CSS:

```
.text { white-space: pre; }
```

б) Реально заменяя перевод строки на <br>. Я бы рекомендовал делать это так:

```
echo nl2br($text);
```

и если вы экранируете теги, то делать это после экранирования.

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text));
```

**UPDATE**: Я был невнимателен, не заметил, что речь идет о textarea. В ней проблем с LF не должно быть по определению! Вы сами что-то поправили в тексте, поэтому переводы строки пропали.

Comment: если добавлять теги br, то они будут отображаться же как текст в textarea, это немного не то

Comment: Чтобы в textarea текст оставался как был, вы *не должны его менять* никаким образом при сохранении в БД! А при выводе просто экранируйте спецсимволы через htmlspecialchars/htmlentity, чтобы _возможные_ теги  не порвали разметку. Переводы строки никуда не денутся!

Comment: в том то и дело, что перед занесением в базу он проходит обработку

Comment: Ну так уберите обработку! Внезапно™

Comment: ну да, конечно, а вы все, что получили от пользователя, заносите в базу без обработки?

Comment: Нормальный сценарий такой: при сохранении используете плейсхолдеры или пропускаете через mysqli_real_escape_string, чтобы избежать sql-inj — И ТОЛЬКО! НИКАКОЙ СПЕЦОБРАБОТКИ. А при выводе экранируете теги чтобы избежать js-inj.

Comment: насчет этого согласен, но в том и дело что там столько всего намучено, включая bbcode, смайлы и еще черт пойми что, что я боюсь убрать все эти обработки без последствий, поэтмоу приходится изощряться

Comment: Принцип MVC: одни и те же данные могут иметь разные представления. Не надо впихивать представление на уровень хранения. Разве не очевидно? Я много работал с движками форумов: везде трансляция bbcode происходит при **выводе**!!!

Comment: Вы заложили "костыль", сейчас чтобы исправить его вам понадобится новый костыль, он будет иметь свои побочные эффекты и потребуются новые костыли и т.д. до бесконечности.

Comment: насчет костыля вы правы, но заложил его не я) я лишь добавил свой. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30188/discussion-between-artoodetoo-and-vadim-k).

Answer (score 0):

Всё там хорошо, textarea нормально понимает переносы строк:

```html
<textarea>Первая строка
и вторая</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 str_replace("\n", '&#10;', $text)
```

сделал так, и теперь все переносы строки отображаются нормально